# As of now (October 2012) How long does it take for Google Play Store to accept an app submitted?

Tags: android, google-play

As the title says,

As of now (October 2012) How long does it take for Google Play Store to accept an app submitted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted an app last weekend, and it was viewable in the Google Play Store within an hour.

Comment: Did they review it or it was automated ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. It was my third app so it may have been automated. Maybe they review the first app and assign some amount of trust to developers after that?

Comment: it is automated, usually takes 3 hours or less, probably due to caching refreshes in a database somewhere